# Mean Squared Error (MSE) Issue

Tags: matlab

When I execute the following code to find the mean squared error on different computers (MATLAB), I receive different answers. Does anyone have an idea on why this is the case?

```
function [mse,psnr] = mse_psnr(im1,im2)

N = size(im1);
acc = 0;

for k1=1:N(1)
  for k2=1:N(2)
     acc = acc+ ( im1(k1,k2) - im2(k1,k2) )^2;   
  end
end

mse  = acc/(N(1)*N(2));
psnr = 10*log10((255^2)/mse);
```

Comment: What are the different answers?

Comment: What are the matlab versions you are using? what are the platform (OS) you are using on either machines? what are the input data type of `im1` and `im2` is it possible they are of type `uint8`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try and vectorize the code to remove the nested loop:

```
function [mse psnr] = mse_psnr( im1, im2 )
% make sure input data type is double
im1 = double(im1);
im2 = double(im2);
acc = sum( (im1(:)-im2(:)).^2 ); % instead of nested loop...
mse = acc / numel(im1);
psnr = 10*log10( (255^2)/mse );
```

Comment: Note, assuming `im1` and `im2` are real (not complex), the nested loop sum squared line can likely be made faster by `acc = im1(:)-im2(:); acc = acc'*acc;`. If one is doing this over a whole image, as the variable names suggest, this could be beneficial.